# How to find the bounds in random variable transformation?

Tags: probability, random-variables, transformation

This is Example 2.1.2, from Casella and Berger's book Statistical Inference, Page 49.

Suppose X has a uniform distribution on the interval $(0,2\pi)$, that is,

$$f_X=
\begin{cases}
1/(2\pi) & 0<x<2\pi \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Consider $Y=sin^2(X)$. Then
$$P(Y \le y) = P(X \le x_1) + P(x_2 \le X \le x_3) + P(X \ge x_4)$$

[image: Graph of Transformation]

My question: How did they come up with those cut-offs at $x_1, \dots, x_4$? What happened to the interval between $x_1$ and $x_2$, $x_3$ and $x_4$? The book does a poor job and never explained.

Can someone solve this question step-by-step? Thank you!

Comment: 1. I don't know what do you mean by "cutoffs", but the solution to inequality $\sin^2 x\le y$ is $[0,x_1]\cup[x_2,x_3]\cup[x_4,2\pi]$. Is that your question? 2. A better (in my opinion) approach to solving this kind of problems is described in my answer [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531572/density-of-x2-when-x-has-uniform-1-2-distribution/1531597#1531597). It quickly gives you the answer $1/(\pi \sqrt{y(1-y)})$. 3. The book does a *great* job in explaining this example by giving the picture which is worth a thousand words.

Comment: Your answer is just a formula, quite abstract. I don't understand the math.

Comment: Then go read the books. The understanding does not come by itself.

Comment: The book is too brief for beginners. For the problem, the reason is that you want to find all points less than or equal to y in the transformation $y=sin^2(x)$, that's why there is a horizontal bar. Your linked explanation has nothing to do with my question. Just saying.

Comment: I wrote "book**s**", not "book". There are many introductory texts in calculus and statistics.

Comment: Can you name one that's actually good?