# If $X \sim Unif([-1,2])$ and $Y=(X-1)^{2}$, find the PDF of $Y$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I can find the range of $Y$ easily but I get lost going anywhere past this because this is not an invertible function because $(X-1)^2$ does not pass the horizontal line test on this interval so I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: I don't have the time to work out the details, but maybe a [computer generated](https://imgur.com/a/R6C09Zi) answer will guide you towards the solution. Note also that if your function $Y$ is interval monotonic, you can work out the solution for each interval where the function is invertible.

Comment: Find the pdf of $X-1$ and use the methods discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531572/density-of-x2-when-x-has-uniform-1-2-distribution?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2842360/if-x-has-a-u-1-3-distribution-and-y-x2-find-the-probability-density?noredirect=1&lq=1).