# Transforming of Random Variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $X \sim \text{Uniform} ( -1,3)$. 
Find the PDF of $Y= X^2$.

Solution:
The  density of $X$ is
$$f_x(x)  = \begin{cases} 
  \frac {1}{ 4} &  \text{if }  -1< x  < 3  \\
0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

$Y$ can only take values in $(0,9)$. Consider two cases: (i) $0 < y < 1$ and (ii) $1 < y < 9$. For case (i), $A_{y1} = [-\sqrt{y}, \sqrt{y}]$.  For case (ii) $A_{y2} = [-1,\sqrt{y}] $

$$F_Y(y) = \int _{A_{y1}} f_X(x)dx  =  (1/2)\sqrt {y} $$

$$F_Y(y) =  \int_{A_{y2}} f_X(x)dx   = (1/2)(\sqrt {y} + 1)$$

Differentiating $F$ we get

$$f_Y(y) = 
 \begin{cases}  \frac {1}{ \sqrt y } & \text{ if } 0 < y < 1  \\
  \frac {1}{8 \sqrt y }  & \text{ if } 1 < y < 9 \\
0 & \text{otherwise } \end{cases}$$

I don't get how the two cases were considered and then from those two cases limit of integrals $A_{y1} $ and $A_{y2} $ were calculated?

Comment: Previously asked: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2842360/321264.

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233821/why-is-y-separated-into-two-intervals

Answer (score 0):

Let us start with CDF of $Y$: 
$$
F_Y(y) = \mathbb P(Y\leq y) =  \mathbb P(X^2\leq y).  
$$

If $y\leq 0$, $X^2$ cannot be less or equal than $y$, so this probability is zero. 
Therefore we can consider $y>0$ only. In this case 
$$
F_Y(y) = \mathbb P(X^2\leq y)=\mathbb P(|X|\leq \sqrt{y})=\mathbb P(-\sqrt{y}\leq X\leq \sqrt{y}).  
$$
And $X$ takes only values from $-1$ to $3$. There are two cases:

1) If $[-\sqrt{y},\sqrt{y}]$ is inside $[-1,3]$, then to find probability, we need to integrate PDF $f_X(x)$ in these bounds. It happen when $0<y\leq 1$.
For this case 
$$
F_Y(y) = \int\limits_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}}f_X(x)dx.
$$

2) If $1<y\leq 9$, then $\sqrt{y}\in[1,3]$ and $-\sqrt{y}<-1$ is outside $[-1,3]$, so the lower bound of integral should be $-1$. 
For this case 
$$
F_Y(y) = \int\limits_{-1}^{\sqrt{y}}f_X(x)dx.
$$

And also for $y>9$, $[-1,3]\subset [-\sqrt{y}, \sqrt{y}]$, so 
$$
F_Y(y) = \int\limits_{-1}^{3}f_X(x)dx=1.
$$