# $X\sim\text{Unif}[-1,2]$ find PDF of $Y=X^2$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$X\sim\text{Unif}[-1,2]$ find PDF of $Y=X^2$

Would someone mind explaining to me the parts of the solution I'm confused about?

"Since $-1\le X\le2$ and we have $0\le X^2\le4$"
I understand the 4 cause that's $2^2$, but why is it 0 and not 1? I'd assume $1\le X\le4$ because it's $[-1,2]$ and $-1^2=1$ and $2^2=4$.

Then
$$f_Y(y)=F_Y'(y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt y}f_X(\sqrt y)+\frac{1}{2\sqrt y}f_X(-\sqrt y)$$

"For $0\le y\le1$ then $f_X(\sqrt y )$ and $f_X(-\sqrt y )$ is equal to 1/3", which makes sense since y=$x^2$ so $\sqrt0$ and $\sqrt1$ will be within the bound [-1,2].

"For $1<y<4$ we have $f_X(\sqrt y)=1/3$ and $f_X(-\sqrt y)=0$"

Is $f_X(-\sqrt y)=0$ because $-\sqrt 1=-1$ which is not considered part of [-1,2] because it's at the end of the bound?

Comment: $X$ can take values between $-1$ and $0$ and between $0$ and $1$ and between $1$ and $2$, so $X^2$ can take values between $0$ and $1$, and between $0$ and $1$ (again), and between $1$ and $4$, i.e. overall between $0$ and $4$

Comment: As a related example, consider what goes wrong in this calculation: Let $y=x^2$. Then $dy=2x\, dx$, so $$\int_{-1}^1 x^2\,dx=\int_{1}^1 y (2\sqrt{y})^{-1}\,dy=0$$ because the endpoints are identical. But $x^2>0$ except at the origin, so there’s no way the integral can vanish.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [density of $X^2$ when $X$ has uniform $[-1, 2]$ distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531572/density-of-x2-when-x-has-uniform-1-2-distribution)